# Trying to run a Python script with cron, getting [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Tags: python-3.x, cron, macos-catalina

So I have a Python script which just pulls information from APIs and sends an email. When I run it manually, it works. I have a cron job set up:

```
30 7 * * * /Users/myname/anaconda3/bin/python3 /Users/myname/Desktop/repo/somefolder/script.py >> /Users/myname/Desktop/filename.log 2>&1
```

but the output in filename.log is:
/Users/myname/anaconda3/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/myname/Desktop/repo/somefolder/script.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

I've tried lots of different things involving trying out different file permissions, creating the cron job as root, adding a shebang, and different Python paths, but cannot get any output other than this error. Nothing I've found online has given a different result so far.

I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.1.
The file permissions currently for my script:

```
-rwxr--r--  1 myname  staff  4161 13 Nov 18:07 /Users/myname/Desktop/repo/somefolder/script.py
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you post the log with the error?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for, but the line in my post is all that gets written to the log file.

Comment: I am guessing this: your file permissions are incorrect,
as a quick test change the permission to: chmod 755 [filename]

Comment: DIdn't work unfortunately, I got the same error.

Comment: @ap1997 did you figure it out?

Answer (score 6):

I had a very similar issue with attempting to run a node.js script using crontab in MacOS. In order for me to finally get it to work, I had to add `cron` and `zsh` to the Full Disk Access in my Security and Privacy settings in System Preferences.

How to add cron:
1. Apple Menu -> System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Full Disk Access
2. Click the Lock to Allow Changes
3. Click the + Sign
4. hit Command + Shift + G and in type '/usr/sbin/'
5. scroll to find "cron" in the list of binaries
6. Click "Open"

How to add zsh:
1. repeat steps 1 - 3
2. hit Command + Shift + G and in type '/bin'
3. scroll to find "zsh" in the list of binaries
4. Click "Open"

After I did that my cron jobs ran without issue. Hope that helps